Как отлаживать .cpp файлы в NeoVim?
Я поставил codelldb дебаггер в Nvim'е и настроил его взаимодействие в вимом используя DAP(ниже приведу код файлы dap.lua). Вроде бы он работает: брейкпоинты ставит, отладку запускает. Но я так и нигде не нашел как передавать аргументы в консоль(например, при вызове std::cin). Так же при простом запуске отладки в режиме Debug не активны кнопки шагов(step into, step over) - работает только кнопки перезапуска отладки и остановки ее.

Mой dap.lua в ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/
 return {
 {
     "julianolf/nvim-dap-lldb",
     dependencies = { "mfussenegger/nvim-dap" },
     config = function()
         require('dapui').setup()
         local cfg = {
             configurations = {
                 c = {
                     {
                         name = "Launch debugger",
                         type = "lldb",
                         request = "launch",
                         cwd = "${workspaceFolder}",
                         program = function()
                             local out = vim.fn.system({ "make", "debug" })
                             if vim.v.shell_error ~= 0 then
                                 vim.notify(out, vim.log.levels.ERROR)
                                 return nil
                             end
                             return "path/to/executable"
                         end,
                     },
                 },
             },
         }
         require("dap-lldb").setup(cfg)
     end
 },
 {
     "rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui",
     dependencies = {
         "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
         "nvim-neotest/nvim-nio"
     },
     config = function()
         local dap, dapui = require("dap"), require("dapui")
         dap.listeners.before.attach.dapui_config = function()
             dapui.open()
         end
         dap.listeners.before.launch.dapui_config = function()
             dapui.open()
         end
         dap.listeners.before.event_terminated.dapui_config = function()
             dapui.close()
         end
         dap.listeners.before.event_exited.dapui_config = function()
             dapui.close()
         end

         --setting keybindings
         vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>db', dap.continue, {})
         vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dt', dap.toggle_breakpoint, {})
         vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dr', dap.restart, {})
         vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>dc', dap.disconnect, {})
         vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>gb', dap.run_to_cursor, {})
     end,
 },
 {
     "jay-babu/mason-nvim-dap.nvim",
     dependencies = {
         "williamboman/mason.nvim",
         "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
     },
     config = function()
         require("mason-nvim-dap").setup({
             ensure_installed = { "codelldb" }
         })
     end
 },
 {
     "mfussenegger/nvim-dap",
 },
 }


Программа которую дебажу
 #include <iostream>
 int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
     int a;
     std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
     std::cout << "That's yout number: " << a;
     std::cin >> a;
     return 0;
 }


Вот как выглядит мой экран, после того как я запустил отладку.



Можете подсказать что у меня не так? Просто везде искал и нигде нормального ответа или хотя бы примерного конфига не нашел.

Логично что "step" не работает пока программа не поставлена на паузу.
